# How to get product categories for a product in a specific store with REST?

Tags: category, api

from the documentation, in order to get the product categories for a product the request url looks like this:

```
http://www.bla.bla/magento/api/rest/products/{productid}/categories
```

I have tried several combinations for filtering with store including the following:

```
http://www.bla.bla/magento/api/rest/products/{productid}/categories/store/{storeid}
```

Any feedback most welcome.

Comment: do you get an error message or simply no categories?

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use this:

```
http://www.bla.bla/magento/api/rest/products/{product_id}/categories/?store={store_id}
```